# C# with SQL: Populating multiple comboboxes each with different columns of same table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox, sqldataadapter

as stated in the title, I would appreciate some help with populating comboboxes with different columns of the same table

I don't have the actual source codes with me but I was able to populate one combobox with something like

```
SqlDataTable dt = new SqlDataTable();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = comm;
da.Fill(dt);
myCMB.DataSource = dt;
myCMB.DisplayMember = "display";
myCMB.ValueMember = "value;
```

but I have 5 comboboxes, and I didn't want to repeat the same blocks of code 5 times just for that. so I looked around and found some answers, including changing datasource to bindingsource, like so:

```
myCMB.DataSource = new BindingSource(da, "Column_Name");
```

but doing so would populate the combobox with each letter of the first item of the specified column (ie. if the first item in "Column_Name" is ABCD, my combobox options would be A,B,C,D)

So, I tried looking for more answers but I can't find any. is there a more efficient way of populating my comboboxes or do I really have to repeat essentially the same lines of code for each of them? if anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do like `myCMB.DataSource = dt;
myCMB.DisplayMember = "col1";
myCMB.ValueMember = "col2"; myotherCMB.DataSource = dt;
myotherCMB.DisplayMember = "col3";
myotherCMB.ValueMember = "col4";`

Comment: when you say "different columns of the same table", that means datatable or sql table.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but I'd like to thank @ChetanRanpariya for giving me a correct answer. I don't know how to mark your comment as an official answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a copy of the datatable:

```
SqlDataTable dt = new SqlDataTable();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = comm;
da.Fill(dt);

myCMB.DataSource = dt.Copy();


myCMB.DisplayMember = "display";
myCMB.ValueMember = "value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Value");
dt.Columns.Add("Display");

string query = @"SELECT ID AS ID, Description AS CODE FROM [Tender] ORDER BY ID";
SqlDataReader sqlReader = new SqlCommand(query, DB.SQLConnection).ExecuteReader();

while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlReader["CODE"].ToString()))
        dt.Rows.Add(sqlReader["ID"].ToString(), sqlReader["CODE"].ToString());
}

cbPayment1.DisplayMember = "display";
cbPayment1.ValueMember = "value";
cbPayment1.DataSource = dt;
```